# Is it possible to programmatically start multiple Spring Boot micro services in a single JVM

Tags: spring-boot

During development, it is difficult to start dozens of JVM's manually.

In docker there is the concept of "packing", is it possible to "pack" multiple Spring Boot micro services into a single JVM?

Comment: Everything is possible with sufficient `ClassLoader` tweaking. :-)

Comment: Hmmm. Why not use a script, maven (if you're using maven), or any other means, to start your microservices at ease? I believe the idea of having a single JVM to all of your microservices would defeat the purpose. A single microservice instance SHOULD have its own domain, database, and PROCESS.

Comment: Trying to simplify the local dev/test cycle ... starting/stoping 20 micro services is annoying, restart is order-dependent